# Submit form only if a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, checkbox

I'm trying to submit a form with javascript, I need that when verifying a checkbox send the form automatically, in a few seconds.

```
<form  method="POST" action="{{ route('turnox', $event->id) }}">
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            Confirmar Asistencia: 
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label class="switch s-icons s-outline s-outline-success mr-2">
                <input name="cconfirma" type="checkbox">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            Cancelar Turno: 
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label class="switch s-icons s-outline s-outline-danger mr-2">
                <input name="ccancela" type="checkbox">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

If someone verifies a checkbox, the form is submitted automatically.

Comment: If you check the box, then after a while the form should submit data?

Comment: yes, after a few seconds send the data

Comment: add `required` as `<input name="cconfirma" type="checkbox" required>`

Comment: I already tried, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let interv
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.type === 'checkbox') {
      console.log('form submitting in 1 second')
      interv = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('form submitting...');
        // e.target.closest('form').submit();
      }, 1000)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('turnox', $event->id) }}">
  <!--           {{method_field('PUT')}}
@csrf -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Confirmar Asistencia:
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label class="switch s-icons s-outline s-outline-success mr-2">
    <input name="cconfirma" type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Cancelar Turno:
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label class="switch s-icons s-outline s-outline-danger mr-2">
    <input name="ccancela" type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/aVihDjS.png  does not send the data when I checkbox

Comment: @user13523236 I forgot to mention, uncomment that line that will submit the form. I commented it out for the  snippet